# Multiple NSXML Parser Issue

Tags: iphone, xml, nsxmlparser

I am trying to parse two different XML files that are hosted on a server in an iPhone app. I have moved the parser from the AppDelegate to each of the ViewControllers but am having issues where none of my data is appearing parsed into the two tableViews. Each ViewController has a tableView; one to parse a file called "Articles", the other to parse a file "Headlines". I was able to successfully parse data when the nsxmlparser was initialized in the appDelegate, but now that I have split it apart and created two parsers, each in the viewControllers, my data is not parsing properly.

Comment: What u find in debug process?

Comment: putting some code will be much helpful

Answer (score 0):

**Things to check**

- All values are properly initialized
- Input is there(check the network is returning your xml data as input
  to the parser)
- Verify there parsing happens
- Check the errors in parsing any misspelled tags and all
- Check the output inside the parsing loop get correctly populated